# Error when trying to view uploaded ruby on rails application on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, heroku

I'm having problems with trying to view my first Ruby on Rails application on Heroku as a user called LHH has helped me with the first problem which has been about an error uploading but anyway, that has been fixed and now I'm having the problem where I cannot view the application as I am getting the following error.

"We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information"
Error - http://prntscr.com/aepg5c

I opened the log for the deploy that claims it was successful and this is the complete log in this screenshot - http://prntscr.com/aerjnv

---

I'm not really one to be using ruby on rails as this is my first application that worked and I don't use the Heroku toolkit so what I'm doing is linking it to github via the browser page and telling it where to get the files and the reason why I'm not using the command line is because for some odd reason the Heroku toolkit isn't working with my Windows 10 system.

Comment: can you set the environment production to development. So you can check  if errors `RAILS_ENV=development`.It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `Gemfile.lock` and remove

```
PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32
```

then add and try to push on heroku.

```
PLATFORMS
  ruby
```

for more check here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile

Comment: Alright I have tried to do this and made sure that the file changed when uploaded to github and it doesn't work for me, the heroku deploy module tells me that everything is ok and ready but still shows up the same problem. [Heroku Deploy](http://prntscr.com/afos3e) | [Gemfile.lock contents](http://prntscr.com/afotj4) | [Heroku log](http://prntscr.com/afoums)

Comment: did you check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile this link ? i have mentioned above.